# Check date against a range of dates in a t sql table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table containing public holidays we take here in the UK. I want to be able to check a given date against these dates and if a date is found in this table then I can perform some calculations. Here is what I have so far. Would I need a while loop to to check each date against @date ?

```
declare @publicHoliday  date;
set @publicHoliday = (Select [HolidayDate] from [table].[dbo].[Holidays]);

if(@date) = @publicHoliday

-- If found then do some calculation stuff
```

Comment: What calculations do you want to do? In theory you should be able to do everything with a set based operation.

Comment: I don't want to go into the calculations part as it is very, very complicated. For many reasons I have to use a cursor, I am only processing a low amount of records so this method is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **IN**:

```
if(@date IN (Select [HolidayDate] from [table].[dbo].[Holidays])) THEN
-- Do your calculation stuff
```

Be careful with your date format. It has to be **DATE** otherwise you will compare also the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if @Date is a public holiday then try this:

```
if exists(Select [HolidayDate] from [table].[dbo].[Holidays] where holidaydate = @date)

-- If found then do some calculation stuff
```